# combining class="{{...}}" expression w/ ng-class="{'className' : boolean}" expression?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, ng-class

I have the following code inside the link function of a custom directive that generates a dynamic map using d3...

```
map.append("g")
.selectAll("path")
.data(topojson.feature(counties, counties.objects.counties).features)
.enter()
.append("path")
.attr("d", geoPath)
.attr("class", function (d) { 
    return "county {{vm.showSalesAreas.data ? vm.getClass('" + d.properties.COUNTYFP + "') : ''}}"; 
})
.attr("ng-class", function (d) {
     return "{'active': vm.toggleActiveCountyFP == " + d.properties.COUNTYFP + ", 'highlight': vm.fipsList.data.indexOf('" + d.properties.COUNTYFP + "') > -1 && vm.showSalesAreas.data == false}";
})
.attr("id", function (d) {
    return d.properties.COUNTYFP;
})
.attr("tooltip-append-to-body", true)
.attr("uib-tooltip", function (d) {
    return d.properties.NAME;
})
.call(function () {
    $compile(this[0].parentNode)(scope);
});
```

FYI, `vm.salesAreas.data` is a boolean

How can I combine these two into one expression so I can reduce the number of watchers?

The problem I've been fighting is the expression in the "class" .attr() doesn't seem to get evaluated correctly when I put it in the ng-class attribute expression in the form 'classname' : boolean because the classname comes from the vm.getClass() call. Ideas?

I've tried using the line below but despite the vm.getClass() returning the correct class name and it being visible in the source inspection, it fails to apply the class...:

```
.attr("ng-class", function (d) {
    return "{'active': vm.toggleActiveCountyFP == " + d.properties.COUNTYFP + ", 'highlight': vm.fipsList.data.indexOf('" + d.properties.COUNTYFP + "') > -1 && vm.showSalesAreas.data == false, '{{::vm.getClass('" + d.properties.COUNTYFP + "')}}': vm.showSalesAreas.data, 'county': true}";
})
```

Comment: just to confirm `d.properties.COUNTYFP` is changing and depending on that the path's associated class should keep on changing..is this the requirement

Comment: Yes, d.properties.COUNTYFP is changing with each path and it's value is used to determine the appropriate class to assign.

Answer (score 0):

The line below infers that all the path will have class county.

```
enter()
.append("path")
.attr("d", geoPath)
.attr("class", function (d) { 
    return "county {{vm.showSalesAreas.data ? vm.getClass('" + d.properties.COUNTYFP + "') : ''}}"; 
})
```

So this can be made into this

```
enter()
.append("path")
.attr("d", geoPath)
.classed("county", true)//so now all path will have class county 
...
```

Now in side the link function you can have a watch to listen to the changing value and update the classes for the circle like this.

```
$scope.$watch(DATA_WHICH_CHANGE,
              function() {
                  d3.selectAll(".county").classed("SOME_CLASS", YOUR_FUNCTION(d))
              }
             );

function YOUR_FUNCTION(d){
      //this function will return true or false depending on the value of d(which is that data)
}
```

I have  something like this in my mind to overcome your problemset.

Hope this helps!